Can't see logs in Azure Log Stream .NET 8
I want to set up logging for my azure deployed ASP.NET Core web app. I can see the logs just fine when running the app locally, but when deployed to Azure the Log Stream doesn't show anything. In Azure I have my Application logging turned on with the level set to 'Information'.
Here is my Program.cs:
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // configure logging
    var logger = LoggerFactory.Create(logging =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders();
        logging.AddConsole();
        logging.AddDebug();
        logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics(); // Add Azure Web App logging
    }).CreateLogger<Program>();

 // other code
}

And my appsettings.json:
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
  },
  "AzureAppServices": {
    "File": {
      "IsEnabled": true,
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
  },
  "Blob": {
    "IsEnabled": true,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Table": {
    "IsEnabled": true,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  }
}

I've tried to find solutions elsewhere but none seem to work.

You needn't configure the Azure stream log in the code. Just open the Azure portal - this App service- monitoring- App Service logs. Turn on the Application Logging with level Information. Then the Log Stream will disaply.



I've done all of that before I posted and it doesn't work. That's why I've made this post :)
